# Could not build module '...' bugs in XCode 14.3 with SwiftUI, building for iOS 14.0

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging, module

I'm currently having a lot of bugs that I don't find solutions for. I have 11 bugs of the type: Could not build module '...' . Do you have an idea on how to solve these?

Here are some examples:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS16.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accessibility.framework/Headers/AXFoundation.h:8:9 Could not build module 'CoreGraphics'

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS16.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Headers/CFNetwork.h:18:10 Could not build module 'CoreFoundation'

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS16.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFStream.h:20:10 Could not build module 'Dispatch'

Here is everything I did to try to solve the problem:

- delete the pods and reinstall them
- uninstall and downloaded again XCode
- clean the build folder and the simulator
- restart my computer
- create a new XCode project
- delete Derived Data

Nothing worked

Answer (score 3):

You can also delete the DerivedData.

Comment: Thank you Sorin! I also tried that actually. Didn't work either...

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! @PaulChatelain try to reset all your dependencies after the deletion of the DerivedData

Comment: This should be the accepted answer